# How to extract data using multiple delimited values in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have the below string in logs with multiple delimiters (: = and #). I am expecting all the values in tabular formate like

```
 tenant |countryCode |deviceType |platformID|paymentMethod1|paymentMethod2|userAgent
 XYZ    | US         | IOS        |13        |p1            |p2            |Mozilla /20.0.553 Mozilla/5.0
```

logs string

```
TrackingLogs tenant=XYZ, countryCode=US, deviceType:IOS, platformID:13,currency=USD, paymentMethods:P1 # P1 # P2 # P2 # P4 # , userAgent:Mozilla /20.0.553 Mozilla/5.0
```

I tried for **':'** but no result

```
search string| rex field=_raw "deviceType\:\s+?(?<deviceType>\S+)" |table  deviceType
```

for = I used below query it worked but don't know how to combine it with : and #

```
search trackinglog  | rex field=tenant "(?<tenant>[^\.]*)\.[a-zA-Z]"| table _raw tenant, countryCode , currency , paymentMethods
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the first query is not the separator, but the regex itself.  It expects a space where none exists.  This variation works:

```
| rex field=_raw "deviceType:\s*?(?<deviceType>\S+)" |table  deviceType
```

For better results, however, try the `extract` command.

```
| extract pairdelim="," kvdelim=":="
```